# Cloud Carousel dynamic images not rendering correctly (z-index issue)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have implemented a cloud carousel on my web page, but when the images scoll in a circle, the images on the left don't display correctly when I load dynamic content via php from a database. What happens is the images that are supposed  to be in the behind  actually render in front. see this image to see the problem

[carousel Problem http://gzerodesign.com/images/carouselProblem.png](http://gzerodesign.com/images/carouselProblem.png)

You can see on the left, relay health logo positions in front.  The right side works correctly.  Is this possible to fix when loading dynamic images?

here is my code

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // This initialises carousels on the container elements specified, in this case, carousel1.
    $("#carousel1").CloudCarousel(      
        {   

            xPos: 490,
            yPos:20,
            buttonLeft: $("#left-but"),
            buttonRight: $("#right-but"),
            altBox: $("#alt-text"),
            titleBox: $("#title-text"),
            mouseWheel:true,
            FPS:30,
            speed:0.2,
            mouseWheel:true,
            reflHeight:40,
            reflOpacity:.25,
            reflGap:1,
            yRadius:40,
            xRadius:330,
            minScale:.35,
            autoRotate:'left' 
        }
    );
});

</script>


    <div id="carousel">
         <h2>Success Stories</h2>
         <!-- Define elements to accept the alt and title text from the images. -->

        <!-- This is the container for the carousel. -->
        <div id = "carousel1"  style="width:840px; height:186px; z-index:1; left:-180px;background:none;overflow:scroll;">            
            <!-- All images with class of "cloudcarousel" will be turned into carousel items -->
            <!-- You can place links around these images -->

              <?php do { ?>

  <a class="thumbnail" href="admin/edit_company.php?co_id=<?php echo $row_rsCompanies['co_id']; ?>" id="trigger"><img class = "cloudcarousel" src="images/logo/<?php echo $row_rsCompanies['co_picture']; ?>"  border="0" />


  <span><img src="images/logo/<?php echo $row_rsCompanies['co_picture']; ?>" />
<?php echo $row_rsCompanies['co_short_description']; ?>
 </span>

</a>
  <?php } while ($row_rsCompanies = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCompanies)); ?>


        <!--end id="carousel1"--></div>
    <!--end id="carousel"--></div>
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I think loading images from db has nothing to do with this. It looks like plugin bug. Try using newer version or write/repair it on your own.

Comment: It actually works fine when I add the images statically, so It must have something to do with the dynamic content.. Maybe I'll try a for loop instead of do/while...

Comment: Try deleting whitespaces in: class = "cloudcarousel" .... Also can you provide link to test this? I would like to look at it source live.